# Print Invoice - Is there a difference between local and live version?

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, php, invoice, pdf

I put my latest local version live. Now I have the problem that I can't print invoice pdfs anymore. Packing slips, orders and credit-memos work without problem. On my local version, there was never an issue.

error report tells me that

`a:5:{i:0;s:172:"Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /bentoLunch/bentoLunch/app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Model/Sales/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice.php, line 1";i:1;s:1726:"#0`

What is the difference in printing pdf on local server and now trying to print the pdf on live server? Maybe if I know that, I can fix this somehow. I already read a lot of posts, and I can assure you, there is no `var_dump`, `echo` or `print_r` inside the `Invoice.php`. 
There is also no empty char before the `<?php`.

And another thing. I send a pdf invoice via email after purchase goes through. This pdf is "printed" without problems and attached to the email the customer receives.

####### ########## UPDATE: ############# ##########

There are 12 orders in my overview in admin. I now randomly clicked all of them. And tried to print. One of them was working now. But only once. If I try again, it's showing same error as before. -__-

####### ########## UPDATE 2 ############# ##########

Haha, today another invoice from the list is printable. And this time, also more than once. This is driving me crazy...

Comment: can you please check  other invoice printing or not

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your comment.

Comment: is other other invoice is printing properly or not??

Comment: the invoice that is attached to the email is printed properly, but this is done automatically. Only if I want to do it from the admin area by pushing print button, it is not working

Comment: it may be issue with order item 1726.

Comment: But should it not work on local version as well then? Also the order and credit-memo are working. And they use the same items as the invoice for a specific order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found the answer to this mystery. Well unfortunately the german language has those absurd letters ä, ö and ü. So I used an ä within a comment in the `invoice.php`. And that messed up the headers thing. 
I Don't know why sometimes a print went through but now it's solved.

Comment: Please "accept" your answer. It's perfectly fine to do so (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) and everybody immediately sees you solved your problem.

Comment: Pardon me. I had to wait for some time till I could accept my answer, so I forgot.